# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError in Spring + Hibernate + jersey

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jersey

I have tried to build a web service using Spring + Hibernate + jersey.
It compiles and deploys without any errors, but when I try to access the web service it gives an error.

pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <jersey.version>1.19</jersey.version>
    <spring.version>4.2.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160810</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

web.xml

```
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.erp.platform.ws</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/erp/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml in src/main/resources

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-5.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/erp?‌​useSSL=false;</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <mapping class="com.erp.platform.beans.Policy"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com.erp.platform.beans.Role"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com.erp.platform.beans.User"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com.erp.platform.beans.RolePolicy"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com.erp.platform.beans.UserRole"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com.erp.platform.beans.RolePolicyId"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com.erp.platform.beans.UserRoleId"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

HibernateUtil.java in com.erp.platform.util

```
package com.erp.platform.util;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }

}
```

Error is returned when trying to run this web service:

```
package com.erp.platform.ws;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.sun.jersey.api.core.InjectParam;
import com.erp.platform.beans.User;
import com.erp.platform.dao.BeanDao;
import com.erp.platform.dao.UserDao;

@Path("userManager")
@Service
public class UserManagerWS {

    @GET
    @Path("/getUserList")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<User> getUserList() {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("SpringBeans.xml");
        UserDao userDao = (UserDao) context.getBean("userDaoImpl");
        return (List<User>) userDao.getUserList();

    }

}
```

The error is like this:

```
type Exception report

message java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:420)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause  
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    com.erp.platform.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:18)
    com.erp.platform.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)
    com.erp.platform.daoImpl.UserDaoImpl.getUserList(UserDaoImpl.java:26)
    com.erp.platform.ws.UserManagerWS.getUserList(UserManagerWS.java:51)

root cause
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:244)
    org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
    org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
  org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)


root cause
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:101)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:106)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:40)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:19)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:138)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:110)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:74)
    org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)

root cause
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:676)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:663)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:653)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:638)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:606)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:1857)

root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)
    java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)
    java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.util.TimeUtil.loadTimeZoneMappings(TimeUtil.java:163)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.util.TimeUtil.getCanonicalTimezone(TimeUtil.java:109)
    com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaSession.configureTimezone(MysqlaSession.java:308)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:2474)
```

Comment: You have a prolem with property file: java.lang.NullPointerException
    java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)

Comment: Which property file? Where I can fine it? Can you please give me a suggestion start the find?

Comment: No idea i have only read the stacktrace

Comment: it is something with the timezone

Comment: It is a bug in mysql connector: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79343

Comment: Yes @Jens you are correct. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=81214) in mysql-connector Version 6.0.2

Change to a newer Version of mysql connector. There the bug should be solved.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```